# How to get HTTP status code for REST service in Mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio

I have following Mule flow :-

```
<jms:activemq-connector name="Active_MQ" brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ"/>

    <mule-ss:security-manager>
        <mule-ss:delegate-security-provider name="memory-provider" delegate-ref="authenticationManager" />
    </mule-ss:security-manager>
    <spring:beans>
        <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
            <ss:authentication-provider>
                <ss:user-service id="userService">
                    <ss:user name="username" password="password" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN" />
                </ss:user-service>
            </ss:authentication-provider>
        </ss:authentication-manager>
    </spring:beans>

<flow name="testFlow1" doc:name="testFlow1">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8083" doc:name="HTTP">
  <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="realm" />
</http:inbound-endpoint>

 <jersey:resources doc:name="REST">
    <component class="MyRest" />
  </jersey:resources>

 <logger message="Done !!!!!" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>

     <!-- http://username:password@localhost:8083/myrest   or   http://localhost:8083/myrest and in this case we need to provide username and password from browser-->

 <catch-exception-strategy>
    <choice >
     <when expression="#[exception.getCauseException().getClass().getName()=='org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException']">
     <logger level="INFO" message="Authentication failed exception: #[exception.getCauseException().getClass().getName()]"/>
     <set-property propertyName="http.status" value="401"/>
     <http:response-builder status="401" doc:name="Status code = 401" doc:description="Authentication failed"/>
      </when>
        <when expression="#[exception.getCauseException().getClass().getName()=='org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException']">
      <logger level="INFO" message="Access denied exception: #[exception.getCauseException().getClass().getName()]"/>
      <set-property propertyName="http.status" value="405"/>
     <http:response-builder status="405" doc:name="Status code = 405" doc:description="Authorization exception - Access denied"/>
     </when>
      <otherwise>
      <logger message="An exception has been caught: #[exception.getCauseException().getClass().getName()]" level="ERROR" doc:name="Exception Thrown"/>
     <set-payload value="Error detected while processing" doc:name="Prepare response for client"/>
     <set-property propertyName="http.status" value="500"/>
     <http:response-builder status="500" doc:name="Status code = 500" doc:description="Exception - Sending a 500 Http Status code as Response"/>
     </otherwise>
      </choice>
  </catch-exception-strategy>

    </flow>
```

I have taken the following as reference :- https://github.com/daveEason/mule-example-spring-security/blob/master/src/main/app/mule-config.xml

Now the issue whenever I hit the url :-  `http://localhost:8083/myrest`   ... I get the following exception :-

```
ERROR 2014-10-20 23:06:52,223 [[test].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.03] org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Registered authentication is set to org.mule.module.spring.security.filters.http.HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter but there was no security context on the session. Authentication denied on endpoint http://localhost:8083. Message payload is of type: String
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Registered authentication is set to org.mule.module.spring.security.filters.http.HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter but there was no security context on the session. Authentication denied on endpoint http://localhost:8083. Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.security.UnauthorisedException)
  org.mule.transport.http.filters.HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter:156 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/security/UnauthorisedException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.security.UnauthorisedException: Registered authentication is set to org.mule.module.spring.security.filters.http.HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter but there was no security context on the session. Authentication denied on endpoint http://localhost:8083. Message payload is of type: String
    at org.mule.transport.http.filters.HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter.authenticateInbound(HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:156)
    at org.mule.security.AbstractEndpointSecurityFilter.authenticate(AbstractEndpointSecurityFilter.java:54)
    at org.mule.security.AbstractAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationFilter.java:52)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************

ERROR 2014-10-20 23:06:52,225 [[test].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.03] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: An exception has been caught: org.mule.api.security.UnauthorisedException
ERROR 2014-10-20 23:06:52,520 [[test].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.03] org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message               : Registered authentication is set to org.mule.module.spring.security.filters.http.HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter but there was no security context on the session. Authentication denied on endpoint http://localhost:8083. Message payload is of type: String
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Registered authentication is set to org.mule.module.spring.security.filters.http.HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter but there was no security context on the session. Authentication denied on endpoint http://localhost:8083. Message payload is of type: String (org.mule.api.security.UnauthorisedException)
  org.mule.transport.http.filters.HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter:156 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/security/UnauthorisedException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.mule.api.security.UnauthorisedException: Registered authentication is set to org.mule.module.spring.security.filters.http.HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter but there was no security context on the session. Authentication denied on endpoint http://localhost:8083. Message payload is of type: String
    at org.mule.transport.http.filters.HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter.authenticateInbound(HttpBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:156)
    at org.mule.security.AbstractEndpointSecurityFilter.authenticate(AbstractEndpointSecurityFilter.java:54)
    at org.mule.security.AbstractAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationFilter.java:52)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
********************************************************************************

ERROR 2014-10-20 23:06:52,522 [[test].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.03] org.mule.api.processor.LoggerMessageProcessor: An exception has been caught: org.mule.api.security.UnauthorisedException
```

I wonder why it's generating such exception ..

But if I remove the **exception block** from the code and hit  `http://localhost:8083/myrest` it works fine and ask the **username** and **password** as expected and generate expected result ..

But I wonder why it is generating exception when I am using **exception block** in the code ..
Actually my intention of using  **exception block** is to get and control different http status in different situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two things at play here:

1. Exceptions thrown by the Jersey resources

   Such exceptions must be dealt with by one or several custom JAX-RS exception handlers, registered to `jersey:resources` via one or several `jersey:exception-mapper` elements.
2. Exceptions thrown by `mule-ss:http-security-filter`

   These exceptions are thrown by Mule outside of the scope of JAX-RS, so they must be handled by a `catch-exception-strategy` element, as you did in your question.

Having this combination of error handling should provide you with what you need.

Comment: Thanks David for your response

Answer (score 1):

to retrieve the HTTP code you can use a filter and throw an exception in the flow. Here an example:

```
<message-filter throwOnUnaccepted="true">
   <message-property-filter pattern="message.inboundProperties['http.status'] >= 400" />
</message-filter>
```

Comment: still getting the same exception